# Change values on screen after flipping view gesture detects

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to change values on a screen after swiping views. I mean that when user flips their fingers on screen then a progress bar starts getting values from the server and set values after dismissal on the same screen.
I read many functionalities about ViewFlipper, ViewPager and Horizaontal Pager and many more but nothing finds like I want. Every Options needs all screen data at a time and then the same is responsible for showing it on every page in ViewFlipper.

Please suggest any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work for you to launch an AsyncTask that will start the progress bar and then update the view when the new data from the server is available. This is slightly modified from the example in the class documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html:

```
new GetServerValuesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);

private class GetServerValuesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String[]> {

 protected String[] doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     return getValuesFromServer(urls);
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(String[] values) {
     updateViewWithNewValues(values);
 }
}
```